# Android: cannot load specific site in webView

Tags: android, webview

WebView opens any site except this one.

http://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html

**Edit: After checking the DDMS I get a JavaBinder Exception of !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!**

the code for my webview activity:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
WebView wv;
final Activity activity = this;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    Log.i("webView", url);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);  
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: may be the problem is of comma `,`. What is that `0,7340,L-8,00` in URL.

Comment: all pages on that site have those comma seperators. should that be causing the problem. I know of many apps that view that site with no problems. There must be a way to find the error...

Comment: I use your given Url Its working fine.

Comment: It redirect me to another website your need to go through that because your creating mobile app. I dont know that language so furthure research you need to do.

Comment: I commented on your answer bellow.

Answer (score 2):

I think Your website is tranforming url to http://m.ynet.co.il/Main.aspx [this URL](http://m.ynet.co.il/Main.aspx).

[image: Your Url]

Remove this code if it is not compulsary.

```
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

        if(progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
});
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

My code for the same is

```
WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html");
}
```

Try to use it Directly

Comment: Firstly, this is only one of many url's i am handling in my app so that I can't point to it directly. Secondly, I see that you are opening the page in the phones default browser and not in the internal webView. I need it to open in my webView. And finally, all url's that I handle are asking for a redirect to the mobile site and are working properly. Any thougts?

Comment: No I open it to in my webview conrol but it automaticaly goes into the inbuilt browser

Comment: Exactly. I want to avoid that. I want it to open in the internal WebView like all the other url's i'm handling.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the call to `loadUrl`in your implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`; it's not necessary and actually creates a loop as the loading is already in progress. You only need to `return tue` to ensure that navigation stays within your WebView.

Comment: That is actually necessary in this situation since most websites redirect to the mobile webview (usually starts with m.) Anyway I tried it but no change. It also doesn't explain why all the other url's work. Anything??

Comment: It's never necessary. WebView will handle the redirects for you. Not sure for the original problem, will keep thinking...

Comment: Thanks .hope you could find a solution

Comment: Can you say exactly what you mean by not being able to open the site? Is an error displayed? Or no content shown, etc.

Comment: When in my webview activity i get a bkank page, nothing shown .if i change the code to open in the default browser, all is good. The thing is that it is only happening with this site. All other sites open in my webview.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a problem using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method (below) with this particular site.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

Once this was deleted all was good...